# Error occuring when trying to pass data to the database: (error: column "name" does not exist)

Tags: postgresql, rest, express

I am currently trying to pass data from an express backend to a database.
The original data is passed from a REST-Frontend (not really important at this point I guess).

My post function does look as following:

```
c_app.post('/v1/postAccount', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  { try
    { const { request } = req.body;
      const newAccount = c_pool.query(`INSERT INTO "account"("name", "firstname", "email", "password", "is_admin")
                                      VALUES(
                                        json_attr_value_d_untainted($2, name,  NULL),
                                        json_attr_value_d_untainted($2, firstname,  NULL),
                                        json_attr_value_d_untainted($2, email, NULL),
                                        ($2->>password)::TEXT, 
                                        COALESCE(($2->>isAdmin )::BOOLEAN, false)
                                      ) RETURNING *`, [request]);
      res.status(200).json(newAccount);
    }
    catch (error) 
    { console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({_type_: 'ERROR', _status_: 500, _message_: error.message}); 
    }
  }
})
```

I defined c_app before (  c_app = express()  )

The first console.log is giving the data to the console, so the Data is passed correctly.
When passing the data via the frontend I get the Error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: column "name" does not exist
```

The data is getting passed by this function in the Frontend:

```
async handleSubmit() {
            const data = {
                name: this.name,
                firstname: this.firstname,
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password
            }
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'applications/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            }
            await axios.post('postAccount', data);
```

My database is structured like this:

[image]

Comment: The you might need to `su postgres` to get access to psql.  But the point of this is, something, presumably the database, is saying that the `accounts` table doesn't have a column `name`.  The first step in your investigation should be to determine whether the column names in your code match those in the database table.

Comment: Ok since I am working with pgAdmin4 its easy for me to look for that. The answer is yes. They do match. That's why I am confused.

Comment: I added my db structure in the post